# Threadlocal counter in Clojure

Tags: clojure, thread-local

I have a web app where i want to be able to track the number of times a given function is called in a request (i.e. thread).

I know that it is possible to do in a non-thread local way with a ref, but how would I go about doing it thread locally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a tool for this in [useful](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/5de8a2ff32d351dcc931d0d10cdd4d67797bdc42/src/flatland/useful/utils.clj#L201) called `thread-local`. You can write, for example, `(def counter (thread-local (atom 0)))`. This will create a global variable which, when `deref`ed, will yield a fresh atom per thread. So you could read the current value with `@@counter`, or increment it with `(swap! @counter inc)`. Of course, you could also get hold of the atom itself with `@counter` and just treat it like a normal atom from then on.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a dynamic global var, bound to a value with `binding` in combination with the special form `set!` to change its value. Vars bound with `binding` are thread-local. The following will increase `*counter*` every time my-fn is called for any form called within a `with-counter` call:

```
(def ^{:dynamic true} *counter*)

(defmacro with-counter [& body]
  `(binding [*counter* 0]
     ~@body
     *counter*))

(defn my-fn []
  (set! *counter* (inc *counter*)))
```

To demonstrate, try:

```
(with-counter (doall (repeatedly 5 my-fn)))
;; ==> 5
```

For more information, see http://clojure.org/vars#set

Comment: This only works inside the context of the macro.  If your code is not the caller (like ring or a HTTP server calling your code to handle a request), it won't work.  For example:
Modifying the `(def` like so:
`(def ^{:dynamic true} *counter* 10)`
executing the `(with-counter` and then examining *counter* afterwards:
`(with-counter (doall (repeatedly 5 my-fn))) . 
=> 5 `
   
`*counter*  
=> 10  `

Answer (score -1):

You can keep instance of [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) in ref. And every time you need to increase it just read value, increase it and set back. At the beginning of request you should initialize thread local with 0, because threads may be reused for different requests.

Comment: Surely keeping a ref in a ThreadLocal is easier than the other way around? I'm not sure it makes sense to keep a ThreadLocal in a ref, because ThreadLocals are mutable and not coordinated with refs; retried transactions on them would break anyway.