# thread local variables in clojure

Tags: java, multithreading, clojure, thread-local, thread-local-storage

1. For no other reason than i have a lot of other custom libraries that i have written that run on 1.1.

I need a straight forward way to have thread local variables a lot of the method i have seen are incompatible with this version of clojure.

seen in this [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387098/threadlocal-counter-in-clojure)

e.g.
(thread-local (atom 0)))

(def ^{:dynamic true} *counter*)

don't seem to work for me

So i just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: have you tried `(def *counter*)`? If I recall, symbols with "ear muffs" were by convention dynamic in early versions of clojure.

Comment: Ear murfs are convention used by some to identify atomic variables.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it -- (a) You want to doom yourself to obsolescence by forever living in version 1.1 released 4 years ago and want to use techniques you have not described from a current version -- or -- (b) You have decided to migrate your code base to a current version and don't know how to convert an idiom you've not described to work in a current version.

Comment: I thought normal vars were thread local unless they had a root binding

Comment: The `thread-local` in the answer you linked to is a prettier clojure-style wrapper over the construct used in `vemv`'s answer. It's not clear to me what's wrong with the linked answer that makes this one better, since it just uses the same stuff underneath.

Comment: It didn't seem to be available in the version of clj I'm working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a class for that!

```
user=> (def local (ThreadLocal.))
#'user/local
user=> (.set local 3)
nil
user=> (.get local)
3
```

Comment: Use this to set an initial value of 3
`(def local (proxy [ThreadLocal] [] (initialValue [] 3)))`